# Table Export to CSV not keeping SQLite Date Format

Tags: c#, csv, sqlite

I am trying to export data from sqlite table  to csv file using c# eveything works fine but datetime has been changed to different format. this is sqlite 3 format  for DateTime

> '2014-05-19 14:42:13.000'

and this is csv dateeime format

> 19/05/2014 14:42:13

and  i need this to be in the same format as sqlite3 and this is my code.

```
 SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = m_dbConnection;


            myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId,DateTime,Serial,ShortDeviceId,MatricolaA,Upper(Targa),CommonRoadDescription,RoadCivicNumber,GpsAddress,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription,VehicleBrandDescription,VehicleModelDescription,CommonColorVehicleDescription,VerbaliRuleOneCode,VerbaliRuleOneDescription,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription,VerbaliRuleOnePoints,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  from  VerbaliData";
            //myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(myCommand);
            //myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

            myAdapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();

            if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
            {
                string value = "";
                DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter("I:/test12.csv");

                for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.Write(",");
                    }
                    swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                }

                swOut.WriteLine();

                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.WriteLine();
                    }

                    dr = dataGridView1.Rows[j];

                    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            swOut.Write(",");
                        }


                        value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                        value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                        value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                        swOut.Write(value);
                    }
                }
                swOut.Close();
            }m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the date value to the CSV file, enclose it with the " (double quote) symbol.

Check: But before that open the CSV file in a notepad and see how the values are written there. Normally CSV files are associated with Excel and if you open it with Excel it will try to parse the values based on your current locale settings.